# word for an action that it is easy to be achieve by one but not by another

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that describes an action that it is easy to be achieve by one but not by another.

Comment: Do you mean "an action that can easily be achieved by one person but not by another"? Please clarify (your current sentence is not grammatical) and also give an example of how you want to use this word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the Italian loan word [sprezzatura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprezzatura), which Wikipedia says has an OED entry giving

> studied carelessness

Comment: tks, and keep them comming please!

Answer (score 1):

the closest word I could come up with is :
esoteric
/ˌɛsəˈtɛrɪk,ˌiːsə-/
adjective

intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest.

I hope it will be helpful.